# How to display a text box while selecting an option from a multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web page which has  multiple drop down menu. Now i need to display some text area according to the options selected in the drop down. If it is a normal drop down i can do that easily. But here the problem is need to display multiple text areas on multiple selection of that drop down.
Here is my code

```
<div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">
                                                <spring:message text="Nature of Type" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <select id="nature" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                    multiple="multiple" onchange="ChangeNature(this)">

                                                    <option>Airticket(Round Trip)</option>
                                                    <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                                                    <option value="medical">Medical</option>
                                                    <option value="resident">Resident Card</option>
                                                    <option value="pickupdrop">Airport Pickup/Drop</option>
                                                    <option value="accommodation">First 7 Days Free
                                                        Accommodation</option>
                                                    <option value="other1">Other 1</option>
                                                    <option value="other2">Other 2</option>
                                                </select> <span class="errorspan" id="nature_er">select the
                                                    type</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"
                                        id="airticket_amt">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                <spring:message text="Airticket Amount" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls " />
                                                <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter
                                                    airticket the Air ticket amount</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group multihide" id="visa_amt">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                <spring:message text="Visa Amount" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls " />
                                                <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter the
                                                    visa amount</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group multihide" id="medical_amt">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                <spring:message text="Medical Amount" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls " />
                                                <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter the
                                                    medical amount</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group multihide" id="residentcard_amt">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                <spring:message text="Resident Card Amount" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls " />
                                                <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter the
                                                    resident card Air ticket amount</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group multihide" id="pickupdrop_amt">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                <spring:message text="Airport Pickup/Drop Amount" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls " />
                                                <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter the
                                                    pickup/drop Air ticket amount</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group multihide" id="accommodation_amt">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                <spring:message text="Free Accommodation Amount" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls" />
                                                <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter the
                                                    free accommodation Air ticket amount</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group multihide" id="other1_amt">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                <spring:message text="Other1 Amount" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls" />
                                                <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter the
                                                    other1 Air ticket amount</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group multihide" id="other2_amt">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
                                                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8 ">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row padding6">
                                            <div
class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
        <spring:message text="Other2 Amount" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input id="amount" type='text' class="form-control numcls" />
        <span class="errorspan" id="billinghrs_er">enter the
            other2 Air ticket amount</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
</div>
                                </div>
```

and here is my script

```
function ChangeNature(obj) {
            var selectValue = obj;
            var selected = selectValue.options[selectValue.selectedIndex].value;
            /* var visa = document.getElementsByClassName("multihide");
            var medical = document.getElementById("medical_amt");
            var resident = document.getElementById("residentcard_amt");
            var pickupdrop = document.getElementById("pickupdrop_amt");
            var acc= document.getElementById("accommodation_amt");
            var other1 = document.getElementById("other1_amt");
            var other2 = document.getElementById("other2_amt"); */
            if(selected ==="visa"){
                $("#visa_amt").show();
            }
            if(selected ==="medical"){
                $("#visa_amt").hide();
                $("#medical_amt").show();
            }
            if(selected ==="resident"){
                $("#medical_amt").hide();
                $("#residentcard_amt").show();
            }
            if(selected ==="pickupdrop"){
                $("#residentcard_amt").hide();
                $("#pickupdrop_amt").show();
            }
            if(selected ==="accommodation"){
                $("#pickupdrop_amt").hide();
                $("#accommodation_amt").show();
            }
            else{
                $("#accommodation_amt").hide();
            }
}
```

[image: see the sample image here]

Answer (score 0):

Use a second function.

The first one will be triggered ever time you change the selection of the checkbox. It will change the class of the trigger source (the current active element) and add or remove a class (e.g. `selected`). After this you start a second function named `updateTextAreas`.

Inside this Function you get all you elements with the given class (e.g. `selected`) and walk over the result list. Then you could show the needed text areas and hide all others.

```
function ChangeNature(obj) {
   $(obj).toggleClass('selected');
   updateTextAreas();
}

function updateTextAreas(){
   // hide everything
   $("#visa_amt").hide();
   $("#medical_amt").hide();

   // get all selected options
   $('.selected').each(function(i,e){
       if($(e).hasClass("visa")){
          $("#visa_amt").show();
       }else if($(e).hasClass("medical")){
          $("#medical_amt").show();
       } [and so on]
   });
}
```

Hope I understand you right.

Comment: I cannot understand. Can you please give some example.. Thanks

Comment: I add a small example

Comment: Thank you marcus.. now its working fine. I used an for loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved now. I used the following script.

```
$('#nature').on('change',function(){
            var val = $('#nature').val();
            if(val!=null){
            arr = val.toString().split(",");
            $('.multihide').hide();
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[i]=="airticket"){$("#airticket_amt").show();} 
                if(arr[i]=="visa"){$("#visa_amt").show();} 
                if(arr[i]=="medical"){$("#medical_amt").show();}
                if(arr[i]=="resident"){$("#residentcard_amt").show();}
                if(arr[i]=="pickupdrop"){$("#pickupdrop_amt").show();}
                if(arr[i]=="accommodation"){$("#accommodation_amt").show();}
                if(arr[i]=="other1"){$("#other1_amt").show();}
                if(arr[i]=="other2"){$("#other2_amt").show();}
            }
          }else{
              $('.multihide').hide();
          }
        });
```

Thanks to all.